# How endorser peer refuses to endorse in hyperledger fabric ?How to design chaincode to make it?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

In the official example,the committer peer and endorser peer install the same chaincode,They call the same method and enter the same parameters, and the endorsement peer is definitely successful.

but,

How to design chaincode make the endorsement peer refuse endorsement in some cases?

How endorser peer refuses to endorse in hyperledger fabric ?

Comment: it's possible that using the same chaincode and another endorser can reject the proposal. example, chaincode of Request Data; a user invokes that chaincode and need to get endorsement from other 2 peers. suppose in that chaincode has a function to check for user permission. since user permission in each peer is different so based on this, one peer has a permission list to allow him to access, he will endorse but another peer who has a permission list to not allow him to access will not endorse.

Answer (score 0):

In traditional way of implementing things, each org will have its own code and their own data with them, so there is no trust among the orgs. HLF brings in the trust among orgs as all of them have exactly the same thing - same chain code, data and hence everything succeeds, and yes there is no scope to fail. However, the goal achieved is that no company can tamper with data without breaking the system, so data is trustworthy.

However, starting HLF 2.0 I (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/whatsnew.html) it is now possible to 'extend' chain codes, and chain codes need not be identical across orgs. This means that there can be multiple orgs participating in a HLF network, and each have customized the chaincodes to suite their business requirements.

The design would be like - agree upon common JSON request and response structures, implement chaincode, and each org customizes it according to their choice not breaking the business agreements. While I did not try this 'extend chain code' yet, it now conceptually is possible to not have exactly same chain code, and so a chain code invocation need not always succeed.

Comment: Yes, thank you for helping out, I just answered the question. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, now it looks like an answer. Just that it now is beyond me to judge correctness or helpfulness. My shortcoming, but please understand that I cannot upvote because of it. Good luck. Have fun.